# Manage time offset for different users?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I was looking thru the search here and found lots of way to convert the time in MySQL but am yet to find what would be the best way to manage users time offset.

On the signup of my website I have an option to allow the user to pick what timezone he wants the website displayed in, how should I save the time offset the user picked ?

- A) Should I use the name of the timezone resulting in a
  `VARCHAR` field on my MySQL table ?
- B) Should I use `small int 4` field and store it as -1200 ~ 1300
  format to later reuse for conversion ?

or what would be the most appropriate way to store the time offset in a way it would be later beneficial to me considering it could be reused in queries or on the PHP itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably store the timezone name as a string that you can later directly feed into the [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php) of `DateTimeZone`. It's also human-readable as a bonus.

Comment: Which would also let me use the convert_tz from MySQL right http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz ?

Comment: @Prix: I wouldn't really get involved with timezones on the database. There's no real need to, everything can also be done in PHP (where it's arguably more visible and easier to engineer).

Comment: thanks for the reply, so it would be better to convert the time returned at PHP level then letting MySQL do it ?

Comment: That's what I'd do because this way, you do not need to mess with each query.

Comment: Only down side I could really think of right now is that if I had it converted at MySQL level, and wanted just the time from today I would get it, while if I had it converted at PHP level I would still have to filter the dates due to the conversion that could possible pick some date that would go over's today's date (due to the timezone differences), am I right ? Could there be other possible down sides to it that I missed ?